# How do I 'run' an application locally that consists of multiple EAR and WAR files?

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, websphere

I am looking over an old application repo from 2005 that consists of 4 project packages. There's no documentation to be found anywhere. All I know is that 2 of them contain EARs and 2 of them contain WARs. Is something like this meant to be run as 1 entity in something like WebSphere or do I have to run each EAR/WAR file separately? My goal is to run this application locally so I can call the SOAP web service API endpoints from SOAPUI. I have Eclipse IDE, IntelliJ IDE and WebSphere 9.0 available for this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You need application server WildFly / GlassFish / WebSphere. You can deploy then your application with eather IDE like Eclipse or with admin panel of application server

Comment: Any deployment documentation elsewhere?

Comment: You didnt mention which WebSphere you are running (traditional or Liberty), but in general, you build 2 EARs (which I  assume will contain one WAR each) and then deploy them to the same server (you could deploy to separate servers, but you will consume less resources when deploying to single one).